# Show error.response.data in frontend as a message to the user

Tags: node.js, reactjs, error-handling, axios

I want to show the user error.response.data as a message during signup. error.response.data is either "Email in invalid" or "Email is already registered." I am using React and node and axios.

Comment: Please add your react code that you have tried so that we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Use react snakbar and display the error message whenever error occurs.